# Copy a file including it's relative path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to copy a large number of files to a backup folder but I want to maintain their relative paths. I only need specific files; i.e.

```
C:\scripts\folder\File.ext1
C:\scripts\folder2\file2.ext2
C:\scripts\file3.ext1
```

But I only need to copy the ext1 files like so:

```
C:\backup\folder\File.ext1.bak
C:\backup\file3.ext1.bak
```

The source paths are of multiple depths.
This is what I have to copy the files:

```
$files = gci -path C:\scripts\ -recurse -include *.ext1 
$files | % { Copy-Item $_ "$($_).bak"; move-item $_ -destination C:\backup\ }
```

This just dumps all the files into C:\backup\ and does not appear to get any of the paths. Not sure how that part would be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
gci -path C:\scripts\ -recurse -include *.ext1 | 
  % { Copy-Item $_.FullName "$($_.FullName).bak"
      move-item $_.FullName -destination ($_.FullName -replace 'C:\\scripts\\','C:\backup\') }
```

It is not clever, but it's quick & dirty and works without a lot of effort.

Comment: Might want to double those backslashes in 'C:\scripts\' in the replace.  That's a regex.

Comment: This looks like it will do the job. I will give it a shot and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

get-childitem returns absolute paths, but you can make them relative to the current working directory as follows:

```
resolve-path -relative
```

So to copy a filtered set of files from the current directory recursively to a destination directory:

```
$dest = "c:\dest"
$filter = "*.txt"

get-childitem -recurse -include $filter | `
    where-object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | `
    resolve-path -relative | `
    % { $destFile = join-path $dest $_; new-item -type f $destFile -force | out-null; copy-item $_ $destFile; get-item $destfile; }
```

new-item is needed to create the parent directories

get-item provides a display of all the new files it created

Of course robocopy does all this, but there will be times when you want to do more special filtering or filename mangling...

Comment: You can pass the `-File` flag to `get-childitem` and thus not have to do `where-object { !$_.PSIsContainer }`

Answer (score 2):

Use robocopy.

```
robocopy c:\scripts c:\backup *.ext1 /s
```

Oops.  I failed to notice you wanted to add the .bak extension too.  I still think it is a good idea to use robocopy to copy the files then:

```
dir c:\backup -recurse -include *.ext1 | % { ren $_ "$_.bak" }
```

Comment: I could do this with robocopy yes but I wanted to see if there was a way to do it with purely powershell.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Clear-Host
$from = "'C:\scripts\"
$to = "'C:\backup\"
$inc = @('*.ext1', '*.extx')
$files = get-childItem  -path $from -include $inc -Recurse
$files | % {$dest = (Join-Path $to $($_.FullName+".bak").SubString($from.length)); $dum = New-Item -ItemType file $dest -Force; Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $dest  -Recurse -Force }
```

the new-item is there in order to force path creation.

Jean Paul